# How many splash screen i need to add in ionic project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I am building an ionic app I see that there are multiple folders for splash screen all the folders are having the same image but with different dimensions are default images of course. I want to replace them all with my own image. But I am wondering do I need to make a splash screen of all sizes also?

you can how many folders are there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to replace all images. You just need to put your own splashscreen under the `resources` folder. From [cordova resources documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources)

> The source image for splash screens should ideally be at least 2732×2732px and located at resources/splash.png

#### If you are using `cordova` integration

Then, you just need to run the following command :

`ionic cordova resources android` or `ionic cordova resources android`

It will then set all the specific assets of the chosen platform.

#### If you are using `capacitor` integration

If you are using `capacitor` integration instead of `cordova`, you need to install `cordova-res` by running the following command :

`npm install -g cordova-res`

And then :

`cordova-res ios --skip-config --copy` or `cordova-res android --skip-config --copy`